# How to get the prorate charge from braintree?

Tags: ruby, braintree

I want to show the **prorate charge** to customers, so they know how much they need to pay when upgrading to a different plan. Is there a way to get this charge from braintree?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/recurring-advanced-settings#proration "Proration on upgrades example"

I created a method to calculate the prorate to show to the client before charge. Is not include discount's ou add-ons.

```
 protected function getProrate($mainSubscription, $currentPlan, $upgradePlan)
 {
    // Original monthly subscription price = $30
    $currentMonthPrice = $currentPlan->price;
    // New monthly subscription price = $50
    $newMonthPrice = $upgradePlan->price;
    // Number of days left in the billing cycle = 27
    $nbrDaysLeftBillCycle = Carbon::today()->diffInDays(Carbon::instance(
        $mainSubscription->braintreeSubscription->billingPeriodEndDate), false);
    // Total number of days in the billing cycle = 30 (billingPeriodEndDate - billingPeriodStartDate)
    $billingPeriodStartDate = Carbon::instance($mainSubscription->billingPeriodStartDate);
    $nextBillingDate = Carbon::instance($mainSubscription->nextBillingDate);
    $nbrDaysTotalBillCycle = $billingPeriodStartDate->diffInDays($nextBillingDate);

    // ($50 – $30) x (27 / 30) = $18
    $estimated = ($newMonthPrice - $currentMonthPrice) * ($nbrDaysLeftBillCycle / $nbrDaysTotalBillCycle);

    return $estimated;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I think if you want to obtain a same updated subscription result (with proration) as shown in braintree sandbox, you need calculate $nbrDaysLeftBillCycle as Carbon::today()->diffInDays(Carbon::instance(
        $mainSubscription->braintreeSubscription->nextBillingDate), false);

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions like this, please [get in touch with our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

No, there is no way to get this charge from Braintree, other than either performing the upgrade or simulating the situation in the Braintree sandbox environment (which won't be feasable in many situations).

Comment: After updating the subscription price with proration, inside the resulting subscription object returned and within the transaction array there, I should be able to see the prorated charge, right? But how do I confirm programmably make sure that that most recent transaction is a result of the update I just made (and not the result of another transaction happening asyncronously)? Or is it safe to assume that between my update and the returned transaction list, no other update could have occurred?

Comment: @JosephShih It is safe to assume that the most recent transaction returned to you is the transaction that resulted from the proration.

Comment: Consider, If user have prorate amount for next billing this time user cancel the subscription means this time what will happen on that prorate amount?

Comment: @Win Sorry, I don't understand your question. Please email Braintree support.

Comment: @agf 
I using Braintree Subscription.
From API, how to know which transaction is 'upgrade proration', which is normal 'sale'?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @anhduc.bkhn Please reach out to our support team, they'll be glad to answer.